# What's the fastest / most efficient find/replace app on *nix

Tags: linux, replace, find

I've got a large SQL dump 250MB+ and I need to replace www.mysite with dev.mysite.  I have tried nano and vi for doing find/replace but both choke.  Nano can't even open it, and vi has been doing the find/replace now for an hour.

Anyone know of a tool on *nix or windows systems that does fast Find/Replace on large files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/www\.mysite/dev.mysite/g' dump.sql
```

(requires temporary storage space equal to the size of the input)

Comment: I got bitten exactly by the constraint in the parantheses. Any solutions for cases where so much storage is not available? Or at least tell it where to store the temp file?

Answer (score 4):

Search/replace on a SQL dump is not a good idea

- They aren't text files
- SQL syntax errors are easily introduced
- They contain very long lines sometimes.

What you should do is load it into a non-production database server, run the appropriate UPDATE statements then dump it again. You can use the REPLACE function in MySQL for this.

Comment: Well, it's on of the few ways you can move a production Wordpress or Magento database to a development server.  They contain MANY tables (396 currently in Magento) and it's just not practical to do individual updates.  Just replacing www.mysite with dev.mysite is safe enough.  MySQL Dumps ARE text files (just SQL statements).

Comment: No, MySQL dumps aren't text files. People think they are because they are MOSTLY text files. In fact in practice, loading one into an editor and saving it back out again will usually result in corruption. This is because BLOBs are stored (mostly) in binary form in the text file, and any attempt to interpret them as character data will be incorrect.

Comment: You are correct about them containing non-ASCII data if my database contained BLOBs.  However, I don't, and I don't know of any other solution to replacing a specific string inside the data of 400 tables with thousands of columns combined.  If you have an idea, I'd love to hear it, because at this point it's a major issue for more CMS developers (since you constantly have to move data from production to staging or dev, and it often contains hardcoded links).

Answer (score 2):

you need [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/)

example

```
sed -e "s/www.mysite/dev.mysite/g" your_large_sql
```

alternatively, import the sql into database, then use `replace` to replace for matched strings